# Text Link applying decoration within a flex

Tags: html, css

I have a button set up like this:

`<a href="*LINK*"><button type="submit" class="output loadclass"><img class="btnicon loadclass" src="/assets/thumb.png"><span class="btntext">YouTube</span></button></a>`

After applying styles, it looks something like
[this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQUSp.png)

However, when I apply `display: flex` to the button it functions as intended, but [it shows the underline on the text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMxs7.png).

I've tried setting text-decoration to none but it's still showing up, any idea why?

Comment: `text-decoration:none` on the link?  Not sure why flex would change the underline or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like something got mixed up in your style. Actually, it should work quite easily and flex definitely has no effect on the anchor style within a flex container. Example below:

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;  
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius:20px;
  width: 300px;
  margin:auto;
  gap:10px;
}

.flex a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.flex img {
  border-radius:20px 0px 0px 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="flex">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
    <a href="">link</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it looks like I have to apply text-decoration to the <a> instead of the other elements. Thank you!

Comment: @HypnoticOcelot That was my second assumption and I wanted to write it in my answer. Thank you for your feedback.